# how to use regex grouping to remove all instances for a pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, grouping

I want to replace a request text with "_"

I thought to use java grouping regex syntax. But i got messed up.

here is my input:

> Failed to handle request 0[null->null s:0 w:0.0 a: 0.0 S:0 t: 24543060
>   s(NA) (0 0)] on subject RealTimeUpdate

expected output:

> Failed to handle request _ on subject RealTimeUpdate

**part b**

how can I remove all instances of this pattern in a text?

input:

> Failed to handle request 0[null->null s:0 w:0.0 a: 0.0 S:0 t: 24543060
>   s(NA) (0 0)] on subject RealTimeUpdate. Request was: 0[null->null s:0
>   w:0.0 a: 0.0 S:0 t: 24543060 s(NA) (0 0)]

expected output:

> Failed to handle request _ on subject RealTimeUpdate. Request was: _

here is my try:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\"Failed to handle request\")(\\d)("[")(.*)(\"]\")(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    String output = m.replaceAll("$1"+"$2"+"$3"+"_"+"$5"+"$6"); 
}
```

or

if I'm promised that the pattern starts with `"[null->null"`:

```
str.replaceAll((\\d)(\"[null->null\")(*.)(\"]\")", "X");
```

Comment: what to fix? Is it ok now?

Comment: That doesn't look like compilable Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't now your request syntax exactly, but assuming it's comprised of a number followed by text in brackets, you could use `str = str.replaceAll( "\\d\\[.*?\\]", "_");`.

Comment: how can i add a fixed text to the beginning of the pattern? say the word `request` like this? `str.replaceAll( "request \\d\\[.*?\\]", "_");`

Comment: Yes, you can add fixed test to the beginning just like that. However, it will also replace the word request, together with the rest of the pattern.

Comment: and if i want to leave `"request"` i have to use grouping like @Zabuza answer?

Comment: Or you can use positive lookbehind like redneb suggested.

Comment: Probably will work, but not very robust on different inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Using a zero-width positive lookbehind:

```
str.replaceAll( "(?<=request )\\d\\[.*?\\]", "_");
```

Comment: Is Java-Regex capable of lookbehind? Afaik Java-Regex is far weaker than, for example Perl or PHP Regex.

Comment: I don't know, but it is mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove everything which comes in between `Failed to handle request` and `on subject.*` you may indeed use the java regex grouping. Here's how:

```
output = input;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Failed to handle request (.+) on subject.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String request = matcher.group(1);
    output = input.replace(request, "_");
}
```

Faster would be to catch everything except the request and then put it together:

```
output = input;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(Failed to handle request ).+( on subject.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String beforeRequest = matcher.group(1);
    String afterRequest = matcher.group(2);
    output = beforeRequest + "_" + afterRequest;
}
```

Let's take a look at the needle, the `Pattern`:

```
(Failed to handle request ).+( on subject.*)
```

You can find an explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/xB6yW8/1

Comment: ` output = input.replace(request, "_");` wont replace just one instance?

Comment: It replaces the first instance. However, the matcher will also only find the first request. You can either separate the input (one `String` for each request-line) or do something like `while(matcher.find()) {...}` and replace one occurrence after another.